# String.Format does not work as expected

Tags: vb.net, string.format

I'm need to convert an integer into two decimal string with a + or - sign

```
I.E.:
10 => +10
0=> +00
-9= -09
```

So I try with

```
Sensor1 = String.Format("{0:+D2;-D2}", S1)
```

But I get +D2 instead a positive number.
What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
string.Format("{0:+00;-00}", S1)
```